# PHP XML duplicate nodes need help summing up the values foreach loop

Tags: php, xml, foreach

Apologies up front PHP is not my native programming language.

I have a file that is consuming an XML object and spins through it and sets values so it can update a table.

The file has been changed and there are now two nodes with the same name 'pac'.

I have a foreach loop that sets the values to the final object variable. and I need to add another foreach loop inside that (or maybe I don't PHP people may know better ways to handle incrimental sums on duped nodes in XML).

PHP code:

```
function parseSingleLineFile($singleFilePath,$bundlename)
{   
    $xmlobject = simplexml_load_file($singleFilePath);
    $finalObject;
    $finalObject->timestamp = $xmlobject->Info->Created;

    global $LAST_TIMESTAMP;
    if($finalObject->timestamp != 0) $LAST_TIMESTAMP = $finalObject->timestamp;

    foreach($xmlobject->MeanPublic as $logItem)
    {
        $psplit = split(":",$logItem->Key);
        $parametername = strtolower($psplit[sizeof($psplit)-1]);

        switch($parametername)
        {
            case "exlbnmb":
                $finalObject->exlsolirr = $logItem->Mean;
                break;
            case "solacp":
                $finalObject->intsolirr = $logItem->Mean;
                break;
            case "smaa":
                $finalObject->sma_h_on = $logItem->Mean;
                break;
            case "pac": /* here is the problem spot (there are now two of these...*/
                $finalObject->pac = $logItem->Mean;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add the two mean values and set to the finalObject pac key variable:

Here was my best attempt but I could not test it in production and I cannot recreate this outside of the product system so I so I am not sure I'm right track. I doin't want to risk breaking this at this point of the file's work.

My best guess at getting the mean value for each node:

```
case "pac":
$pacbuilder ='0';
foreach($parametername = pac) {
    $pacbuilder += $logItem->Mean;
}
$finalObject->pac = $pacbuilder;
break;
```

I also want to note that it is grabbing the last pac value and skips the first instance/node.

The finalObject is used to populate a table...

```
if($totalRows_checkForLine == 0)
{
    $query_insertLine = sprintf("INSERT INTO mean_data_table SET 
                                d_exlsolirr = '%s',
                                d_intsolirr = '%s',
                                d_sma_h_on = '%s',
                                d_pac = '%s'
                                ", 
                                $finalObject->exlsolirr,
                                $finalObject->intsolirr,
                                $finalObject->sma_h_on,
                                $finalObject->pac);
    $insertLine = mysql_query($query_insertLine) or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Comment: Inspect $logItem->Mean what is and if it is a actully node.

Comment: What is the output for var_dump( $logItem->Mean)?

Comment: its the 'mean value' so in the xml path there is a node for max, min, and mean and I am grabbing the mean value. :)

Comment: What about $finalObject, is it an instance of $xmlobject?

Comment: It is just a place holder object in a bigger loop.

Comment: Ok but it is important to know if $finalObject hold a $xmlobject instance or what type it is.

Comment: I updated the code so you can see what I do with finalObject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54674/discussion-between-felipsmartins-and-frank-tudor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questioner want the sum of node values when "pac"  >= 2 occurrences and add/to increment to "$finalObject->pac", like this:

```
switch($parametername) {
   //....
    case "pac":        
        $finalObject->pac = (float)$finalObject->pac + (float)$logItem->Mean;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Nice work...And thanks for your help!!! (notice in his answer that not foreach loop is required). +1 +1 +1

Comment: Woops...That would be NOT required...:)